# HELP! jCarousel won't initialise properly!

Tags: jquery

HELP!

My code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.tabs.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#container-1').tabs();
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.tabs.css" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.tabs-ie.css" type="text/css" media="projection, screen">
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7/skin.css" /> <!-- CAROUSEL SKIN/THEME -->
        <script src="jquery.jcarousel.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="init.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem a little while back.

Try calling this part last:

```
<script src="jquery.tabs.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#container-1').tabs();
            });
        </script>
```

From what i remember that was my issue, might not be yours though.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Spot on - I'll vote you up when the SO timer catches up... Never ceases to amaze me how fast StackOverflow peeps are!